# wireguard pc2 --> pc3 --> pc1

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

### I have 3 computers pc1、pc2、pc3

This is the topology of my current network

[image: screenshot]
Usually I use pc2 to access pc1, Network delays are as follows

```
pc2 ping pc1 500ms
pc3 ping pc1 200ms
pc2 ping pc3 100ms
```

#### I want to optimize the above network

pc2 --> pc3 --> pc1 300ms

Is it possible to achieve through wireguard, What should I do ?

#### Additional Information

- Not part of the same LAN pc1、pc2、pc3
- pc1 and pc3 have static public IP, Both are ubuntu 18.04
- I have root control of these three machines
- pc2 is windows 10

#### pc1.conf

```
 [Interface]
 Address = 10.66.66.1/24,fd42:42:42::1/64
 ListenPort = 58241
 PrivateKey = pc1-PrivateKey

 ### Client pc2
 [Peer]
 PublicKey = pc2-PublicKey
 AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.2/32,fd42:42:42::2/128

 ### Client pc3
 [Peer]
 PublicKey = pc3-PublicKey
 AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.3/32,fd42:42:42::3/128
```

#### pc2.conf

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = pc2-PrivateKey
Address = 10.66.66.2/32, fd42:42:42::2/128
DNS = 94.140.14.14, 94.140.15.15

[Peer]
PublicKey = pc1-PublicKey
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = pc1-ip:58241
```

#### pc3.conf

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = pc3-PrivateKey
Address = 10.66.66.3/32, fd42:42:42::3/128
DNS = 94.140.14.14, 94.140.15.15

[Peer]
PublicKey = pc1-PublicKey
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = pc1-ip:58241
```

#### Thank you to everyone

Comment: Do pc2 and pc3 have direct interconnection (e.g. LAN) that you omitted from the topology you show?

Comment: Also, what's the OS on pc3 and how much control do you have over it?

Comment: @TomYan I have added to the original question

Comment: You can set up pc3 as a wireguard server / gateway like you did on pc1, use another wireguard instance and subnet on them (pc2 and pc3), add return route for the subnet / pc2 that take the tunnel between pc1 and pc3. Not sure how better (or worse) the latency will be though.

Comment: @TomYan Thank you, can you give a simple example ```conf```, as a beginner in wireguard, I appreciate this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In pc1 config, remove `[Peer]` entry for pc2
2. In pc1 config, update `[Peer]` entry for pc3 with `AllowedIPs` setting that includes the VPN addresses for both pc2 and pc3
3. In pc2 config, replace `[Peer]` entry for pc1 with `[Peer]` entry for pc3 (including the `Endpoint` address for pc3, and an `AllowedIPs` setting for everything you want to access through pc3)
4. In pc3 config, add static `ListenPort` (`58243` for example)
5. In pc3 config, add `[Peer]` entry for pc2
6. On pc3, turn on packet forwarding (run `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` and `sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1` as root or however you did this on pc1)

Also make sure whatever firewalls you have in front of pc3 allow new connections to UDP port 58243 (or whatever listen port you use for pc3), same as your setup for pc1 with UDP port 58241.

Your 3 configs will now look like this:

#### pc1.conf

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.66.66.1/24, fd42:42:42::1/64
ListenPort = 58241
PrivateKey = pc1-PrivateKey

### Client pc3
[Peer]
PublicKey = pc3-PublicKey
AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.2/32, fd42:42:42::2/128
AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.3/32, fd42:42:42::3/128
```

#### pc2.conf

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = pc2-PrivateKey
Address = 10.66.66.2/32, fd42:42:42::2/128
DNS = 94.140.14.14, 94.140.15.15

### Client pc3
[Peer]
PublicKey = pc3-PublicKey
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = pc3-ip:58243
```

#### pc3.conf

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = pc3-PrivateKey
Address = 10.66.66.3/32, fd42:42:42::3/128
ListenPort = 58243
DNS = 94.140.14.14, 94.140.15.15

### Client pc1
[Peer]
PublicKey = pc1-PublicKey
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = pc1-ip:58241

### Client pc2
[Peer]
PublicKey = pc2-PublicKey
AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.2/32, fd42:42:42::2/128
```

Since you were already routing all internet traffic from pc2 and pc3 through pc1, presumably you already have packet masquerading or SNAT set up on pc1 for that -- keep it, it should still work as before. You *don't* need to add masquerading/SNAT to pc3.